# Timeout connecting to OpenManage after updating to version 9.2 - possible SSL issue?

Tags: windows, ssl, dell-openmanage

I updated my server to OpenManage version 9.2 (from version 9.1 which was working fine), apparently with success. I can run the CLI commands without problems.

My problem is connecting to the OMSA site. I have tried different computers, different browsers (Chrome, Edge, Safari), from the server itself, and I always end up with a timeout connecting to the `https://myserver:1311/` webpage.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled OMSA several times, with no luck.

The only slight improvement I've had is when modifying the tomcat `server.xml` config file: if I disable the `SSLEnabled` setting in the Connector then I do get the login screen, but I can't get past it. I enter the correct credentials, click Login, and then I get again in the Login screen. If I enter invalid credentials I get the expected "login failed" message (so I know the problem aren't the credentials). I'm guessing that internally this requieres the SSL to be working to get past the login.

This makes it clear that the issue is with the SSL connection. Trying to debug it with Fiddler I can see "A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found" and the parameters. But it apparently... never finishes it?

I have removed the certificates (self signed) I found for the server on my computer, expecting Chrome to ask me to accept a new certificate, but no change whatsoever. I have already cleaned (Ctrl+Shift+Del) Chrome history/browsing data, with no luck.

I haven't tried reinstalling version 9.1 to see if anything changes, but I would really like to understand the problem before throwing the towel.

The server is running Windows 2016. The clients I have tried are Windows 10 and MacOS Mojave and the server itself. All the browsers I have tried are up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking further into the tomcat logs, I found a message that said `Keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect` in the callstack of an error when trying to initialize the protocol handler. Something similar to what was mentioned here: https://www.dell.com/community/Systems-Management-General/OMSA-9-2-quot-Keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-quot/td-p/6236906

After that I checked the keystore.db file in the tomcat conf folder and saw that it had a date that was previous to the other files in that folder.

During my uninstalls I noticed that somehow the changes I made to `server.xml` were persisted between installs, even if I used the OMCleanup tool to uninstall OMSA and deleted the folders. The only way I found to avoid this was deleting the server.xml file *before* uninstalling, so I did the same for the keystore.db file. I also restarted the server after the uninstall.

After that, reinstalled OMSA and now the `keystore.db` file had the same date as the other files (and it was after updated to today) and now I can use OMSA without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but recently ran into this with OMSA 9.4 for some reason.  Same problem and similar solution, but I was focusing on C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt... items (which has a server.xml and keystore.db file in there when installed), but found that after uninstall the one that wasn't being removed was under C:\ProgramData...(hidden folder)...\Dell\SysMgt...  After uninstalling OMSA, I deleted the SysMgt folder from C:\ProgramData, then upon reinstall, it finally worked.  Been trying to come with a solution to this on and off for past 3 days.  Was using CLI until i finally got it fixed.  Thanks for the lead on this, but this was what finally got it for me.

Big thing that led to this was the launching of OMSA Icon leads to Page Can't be displayed in IE.  There's a bunch of posts out there about this, but most are because of some other issue not related to this.  I knew the OMSA web server wasn't working because netstat -abn did not yield anything listening on port 1311.  it should show a line like...
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1311           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [dsm_om_connsvc64.exe]

that shows the server is running.  If nothing is listening on port 1311 then the server is not running despite what the service says (DSM SA Connection Service).